# "Direct comparision of a string literal" warnings since last Xcode update

Tags: ios, nsstring, compiler-warnings

Since the last update of Xcode (to v4.6) I've got a bunch of the following warnings:

```
"Direct comparison of string a literal has undefined behavior"
```

This is when a NSString property is compared with another string by this way:

```
if ([self.myString isEqualToString:@"Compare Me"]) { ...
```

Originally I compared with `self.myString == @"Compare Me"` but there are the same warnings. Xcode suggests to use `isEqual:` instead.

I wonder why I should do this. Other comparisons still work, e.g.:

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"nextScreen"]) { // => NO WARNING HERE
```

Edit: OK, for anyone who doesn't believe/downvoters, see this screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I can't see any warnings when using `isEqualToString:`

Comment: Are you sure these aren't old warnings, maybe from a not yet recompiled test target?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes Xcode gets confused and shows old warnings.  I suspect it is showing an old warning for use of `==`.  Clean the build, go to the organiser window and delete the derived data for this project, then restart Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Basically (according to this other [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16246462/fixing-direct-comparison-of-a-string-literal-has-undefined-behavior-automatica), you should switch any of your `==` string comparisons to use `isEqual` or `isEqualToString`.

To make it easier, I found this [post](http://blog.bignerdranch.com/334-isequal-vs-isequaltostring/) on bignerdranch's blog that said there is no difference (in the observable human world) between `isEqual` and `isEqualToString`, so I personally use `isEqual`.

Answer (score -2):

When you use "==", it should, in theory (like in C/C++) compare the pointers, not the value of the objects.

Fact is obj-c (and compiler I guess) will understand what you really want and transform this in isEqualToString. But to be "safe", it's better to use the good method to compare two strings, two numbers etc.

Comment: I get these warnings with `==` and with `isEqualToString:`. Xcode suggests just to use `isEqual:`. I can't understand why `isEqualToString:` throws the warning...

Comment: Oh ok I see. It may be because you try to compare an "id" with a string instead of two strings. Are the two objects "defined" as strings?

Comment: `self.myString` is a property declared in the header the following way: `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *myString;` So it is not an `id`

Comment: Without your project I can't really tell you. If the two objects are NSString, you shouldn't have any problem/warning.

Comment: Neither objc, nor the compiler would "transform" a message to something else.

Comment: The message no, the code, yes. Or any @"" == @"" should never work.

Comment: Identical literals are usually emitted only once by the compiler. Again, there's no magic involved.

Comment: As @NikolaiRuhe says, the compiler will NOT convert `==` to `isEqualToString:`.  In certain situations, you may get lucky and `==` will work only because you happen to be using the same pointer for both strings.  This is not guaranteed however, and may (very likely) even break in a future release.  If you want to compare two strings (or other objects), use the appropriate method and don't compare their pointers!