# Fixing "direct comparison of a string literal has undefined behavior" automatically

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In Xcode, I'm getting the error "direct comparison of a string literal has undefined behavior," and I know why I'm getting it, but is there some way for me to click a button and have Xcode remove it? I'm saying this because in 370 places in my app I've gotten it.

Answer (score 14):

The clang option to disable this warning is `-Wno-objc-literal-compare`.

However, warnings are there for a reason; this one is because comparing against NSString literals using `==` is not guaranteed to behave as you might expect. Use `isEqual:` or `isEqualToString:` instead and you can both get rid of this warning and avoid having this turn into a bug for you later.

Comment: Great answer.  Always use `isEqualToString` vs `==`

Comment: Oh no; I'm talking about having Xcode go through and replace all these errors, just so I don't have to do it.

Comment: There's no one-click "fix all the things that cause this warning", but a well crafted regular expression might make a simple find/replace job of it.

Comment: I was curious if I should use 'isEqual' or 'isEqualToString' and found this [blog post](http://blog.bignerdranch.com/334-isequal-vs-isequaltostring/) that basically said they're nearly the same. So I'd use 'isEqual' for simplicity.

Comment: @JonathanKaufman If you read the article a bit closer, you will find that they are not "nearly the same". `isEqualToString:` gives you type safety, as well as being more explicit in your code, which is never bad. In the odd cases that you need ridiculous performance, or are comparing Unicode characters with different normalizations, as mentioned, use `isEqual:` or `compare:`. Using `isEqual:` does not make things simpler, it's just less typing if you're not doing anything special.

Comment: Also, please don't turn off that warning. It will save you tons of headache in the future. And always strive to make your code compile without warnings as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
You can avoid the warning using `isEqualToString` instead of `==`.        
`==` simply compares the pointers, which will usually be different even   
if their contents are the same. The`isEqualToString` method compares   
their contents.
```